# how to create directory structure on CREATE BLOB action

Tags: azure-logic-apps

**Is it possible to check for the presence of a specific directory structure and create it if it doesnt exist?**

I'm creating a blob like so:

[image]

When the directory doesn't exist, I am getting:

[image]

**How do we create the directory structure when it doesnt exist?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an action in logic app to create a container. So I think you can add a function in your logic app to create the container, then create the blob. I post the screenshot below:

1. Create azure function(here I use v1 runtime version)
   [image]
2. Then add this function to your logic app and provide the request body
   [image]
3. Create the blob and fill in the "Specify folder path to upload" box with /azure because the request body above is "name":"azure".
   [image]
4. Run this logic app, it will create a container named "azure" and create the blob named "testblob".
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Azure Blob doesn't support folder, it's a simulate directory. You may specify a character or string delimiter within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy (e.g., the forward slash `/`). You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata#blob-names).

So you don't need to check for the presence of a specific directory, just name the blob with directory then it will create the folder and the blobs with same directory prefix will be classified in a same folder.

Just name the blob with directory prefix like this `foldername/blobname`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: another words, the container needs to exist, whereas the folder structure will be copied over automatically

Comment: so then the question becomes, _if the container does not exist, how do we force it to be created?_

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', for now the blob connector doesn't support create container, if you need you could go to feedback upvote for [this advice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33202429-add-option-to-create-container-in-an-azue-blob-sto). For now what you could do is like Fury said create a Function to create a conatiner and in logic app you could use HTTP action or Function connector to call it.

Comment: If you still have other problem, please feel free to tell me.